# How to change spinner text color, before and after the field is selected?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have using spinner in my page and i want to change the text color of the spinner text.Before a field is selected it must be in one color and the text color should be differ after the text is selected.

this is my coding

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <Spinner android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/spstate"
            android:prompt="@string/state_prompt"
            android:entries="@array/state_arrays"
            android:popupBackground="#cccccc">
        </Spinner>

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know about spinner text change but you can create a custom spinner in which you can customize anything you want. If you want to try then I can help you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when creating spinner, set default text color in XML:

```
android:textColor="#FF0000"
```

Then change color in onItemSelected() method:

```
((TextView)parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.rgb(249, 249, 249));
```

Comment: Hi, I try this but i getting the data dynamically from the server, so there is any other way to change the color.